# Django forms - is there a way to dynamically edit a FilePathField?

Tags: django, forms

I have a django form which I am using to access a directory. However I would like to access two different directories based on a given input, but have one FilePathField.

As an example - I have two panels - 'panel1' and 'panel2'. The directory I would like to access is the analysis directory of each of these panels as such:

```
/path/destination/panel1/analysis/
/path/destination/panel2/analysis/
```

In each of these analysis directories are directories starting with "Experiment" which I would like a user to be able to choose to obtain some results.

I have my form:

```
class RunUploadForm(forms.Form):

    directory_path = forms.FilePathField(
            path='/path/destination/panel1/analysis',
            required=True,
            allow_folders=True,
            allow_files=False,
            recursive=True,
            match="Experiment*",
            label="Pick folder for results:"
        )


    class Meta:
        fields = ('directory_path',)
```

This only allows the user to access panel1 directory as it is hardcoded into the path arg. Is there a way to dynamically change this path argument, maybe with a choicefield?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way of doing so would be to pass the path as an argument to the `__init__` method of the form, for example:

```
class RunUploadForm(forms.Form):

    directory_path = forms.FilePathField(
            path='/path/destination/panel1/analysis',
            required=True,
            allow_folders=True,
            allow_files=False,
            recursive=True,
            match="Experiment*",
            label="Pick folder for results:"
        )


    class Meta:
        fields = ('directory_path',)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        path = kwargs.pop('path', 'somedefaultvalue')
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['directory_path'] = forms.FilePathField(
            path=path,
            required=True,
            allow_folders=True,
            allow_files=False,
            recursive=True,
            match="Experiment*",
            label="Pick folder for results:"
        )
```

You need to crate a new instance of `FilePathField` because choices for this kind of field are generated on `__init__`

Comment: This is just overwriting the path in init(), not changing the path dynamically. I'm trying to have a way of accessing more than one directory, based on an additional input (This could be all entries from my Panel model...)

Comment: As in, have some kind of radio button within the form which changes the path value.

Comment: Well, you can POST the value of that choice and as a response to that POST return the appropriate instace of the form. Other way would be to do that entirely in the frontend, for example having two different `FilePathField`s in the form and showing/hiding as you need.

Comment: Yes that could work thanks!  Its difficult because when the post is submitted, i only want ONE value being used, but there doesnt seem to be a way of having a default null value..